# Change color of one MaterialButton when other is pressed?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have four `MaterialButton` in a layout and I want to change the color of all buttons when one of them is pressed. Two of them with one color and other two with another color. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Just call `setState()` and use different colors.

Here is an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Color color1 = Colors.blue;
  Color color2 = Colors.blue;

  void _changeColor() {
    setState(() {
      color1 = Colors.red;
      color2 = Colors.green;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Test"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Buttons',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: color1,
            onPressed: _changeColor,
            child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: color1,
            onPressed: _changeColor,
            child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: color2,
            onPressed: _changeColor,
            child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: color2,
            onPressed: _changeColor,
            child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```